# JSON Facebook Payment marked "FRAUD"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-payment-dialog

In the following JSON, I make a payment in the ChefChili game to purchase virtual currency with my credit card (I am not in the payment testers list). This is showing as FRAUD, whereas it was a genuine payment made by me.

https://graph.facebook.com/382606235186483?access_token=193512574007560|75d4646925b860ec194c69d6cd717ad0

The output of JSON code :

```
{
id: "382606235186483",
user: {
name: "Abhishek Srivastava",
id: "100001441415841"
},
application: {
name: "ChefChili",
namespace: "chefchili",
id: "193512574007560"
},
actions: [
{
type: "charge",
status: "completed",
currency: "USD",
amount: "1.00",
time_created: "2013-07-26T11:36:49+0000",
time_updated: "2013-07-26T11:36:51+0000"
}
],
refundable_amount: {
currency: "USD",
amount: "1.00"
},
items: [
{
type: "IN_APP_PURCHASE",
product: "https://chefchili.mediaagility.com/product_desc.html",
quantity: 10
}
],
country: "IN",
created_time: "2013-07-26T11:36:49+0000",
fraud_status: "UNKNOWN",
payout_foreign_exchange_rate: 1
}
```

Also can any one tell me that what is this `"fraud_status:UNKNOWN"?` and why it is showing `"refundable_amount"` ?